# Get the path or the name of the routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, router

I have two routes with a different `path` and `name` but with the same `component`. Is there a way to check what the path is when I navigate for ex. to `/add-user`OR the `name` for ex. `AddUser`

### Routeconfig

app.component.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
      {
        path: '/add-user',
        name: 'AddUser',
        component: UserComponent
      },
      {
        path: '/user/:id/detail',
        name: 'UserDetail',
        component: UserComponent
      }
    ])
```

### Update

#### Usercomponent

user.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
//this is pseudocode
   if (this._router.name == 'AddUser') {
        console.log('you want to add a user')
   }
   else{
        console.log('you want to see the details of a user');
   }
```

Comment: Maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route

Comment: I don't have really found an answer on my question. I want to get the name of the `route` and not of the component

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37050883/217408 returns the route name. Otherwise please improve your question. Add code that demonstrates what you have tried, where you failed. I don't see where you want  to get the current route name. In the `UserComponent`, in the root component, in  a service, ...

Comment: What should `this._router.name = "..."` Why would you assign a name to the `Router`?

Comment: `path: '/add-user', name: 'AddUser', component: UserComponent` it is this `name` that I want to get

Comment: That's what http://stackoverflow.com/a/37050883/217408 shows

Comment: `_router.currentInstruction.component.routeName`did not worked, but `_router.root.currentInstruction.component.routeName` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: That depends on where your code is. In the root component you already get the root router and therefore no need for `root`. Glad to hear you figured it out :)

Comment: I have printed the router so I could see al the properties and functions, and that's how I have seen how to get the routeName

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is: `router.currentInstruction.component.routeName`

Small disclaimer: The new new router introduced in Angular 2.0 RC does not support route names. You might want to avoid using it.

Comment: So it is better to use `urlPath` instead of `routeName`. Because I will have to upgrade to the new version of Angular 2

Answer (score 2):

**>= Angular2 RC.0 <= RC.3**

There are no aliases anymore in the new router.

You can get the relative route of the local component

```
  routerOnActivate(curr:RouteSegment, prev?:RouteSegment, currTree?:RouteTree, prevTree?:RouteTree):void {
    console.log(curr.stringifiedUrlSegments);
  }
```

or the full path using

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}

  routerOnActivate(curr:RouteSegment, prev?:RouteSegment, currTree?:RouteTree, prevTree?:RouteTree):void {
    console.log(this.router.serializeUrl(tree));
  }
```

or

```
constructor(router:Router, private location:Location) {
  router.changes.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.location.path());
  });
}
```

See also [Angular2 get current route's alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479405/angular2-get-current-routes-alias/37207244)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it when I will upgrade my project

Comment: Where did you import location from? e.g. what library?

Comment: FYI `Location` sits in the `@angular/common` library.